# How to enable copy and paste for VNCViewer and VNC server of QEMU?

Tags: ubuntu, copy-paste, qemu, realvnc, vnc-viewer

The VNC server is launched by QEMU 6.1.0 on Ubuntu, the QEMU being built without any special parameters:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda ubuntu.qcow -m 1500
VNC server running on ::1:5900
```

The VNC Viewer is downloaded and installed from [here](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/linux/), on the same Ubuntu machine.

```
VNC(R) Viewer 6.21.920 (r45849) x86 (Oct 14 2021 14:51:02)
Copyright (C) RealVNC Ltd.
```

I run `vncviewer :5900` to view the launched Ubuntu VM. The Ubuntu machine (running qemu, VNC server and vncviewer) disabled GUI for me (i.e., no display, no X server), so I installed `Xming` on my Windows client machine to view it. But I can't copy and paste texts. Also I can't select text by holding and swiping mouse on the VNC Viewer window. This is also the case if I am using a Ubuntu client. How to enable copy and paste in this settings? I have googled hard but with no luck.

[image: A screenshot of VNC Viewer]

Comment: Copy and Paste in a Virtual Machine is enabled by installing Tools, Extensions, or similar.  Do that for your VM and you should be able to copy and paste. I use VMware and and copy / paste

Comment: This is not possible in general. In certain situations (when running X11/Wayland) you could accomplish this using aforementioned guest tools, but that won’t work in a virtual terminal like in your screenshot. // I’m unsure on how Xming suddenly comes into play here. Please elaborate. Is this “Ubuntu system” that hosts the VM perhaps a headless system?